# Protractor find a certain value inside td class

Tags: javascript, loops, protractor, iterated-function

I have been looking on many different examples how to iterate a table.

If I am using code below for selenium I get exactly what I want.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(.,'Apple Pomace')]"));
```

though I would like to instead to iterate the code and find the value below:

```
<td class="ng-binding">Apple Pomace</td>
```

**Notice there are Apple Pomace in two places**

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJAKi.png)

there is my table:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <h3 ng-show="searchQuery" class="page-header page-header-sm"><span translate="TITLE_SEARCH_RESULTS" class="ng-scope">Search Results</span> <span class="label label-default ng-binding" ng-bind-html="searchQuery">Apple Pomace</span></h3>
    <h3 ng-show="!searchQuery" class="page-header page-header-sm ng-scope ng-hide" translate="TITLE_ALL_PRODUCTS">All Products</h3>

    <div class="alert-info ng-hide" ng-show="confirmation">
        <p class="ng-binding"></p>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th translate="LABEL_IMAGE" class="ng-scope">Image</th>
            <th translate="LABEL_PRODUCT" class="ng-scope">Product</th>
            <th translate="LABEL_DESCRIPTION" class="ng-scope">Description</th>
            <th translate="LABEL_PRICE" class="ng-scope">Price</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <!-- ngRepeat: product in products --><tr data-ng-repeat="product in products" class="ng-scope" style="">
            <td><img src="/public/images/products/apple_pressings.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="width: 200px" ng-click="showDetail(product.id)"></td>
            <td class="ng-binding">Apple Pomace</td> //here is the item I want to fetch  'Apple Pomace'
            <td><div ng-bind-html="product.description" class="ng-binding">Finest pressings of apples. Allergy disclaimer: Might contain traces of worms. Can be <a href="/#reccyle">sent back to us</a> for recycling.</div></td>
            <td class="ng-binding">0.89</td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="showDetail(product.id)"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs ng-hide" ng-click="addToBasket(product.id)" ng-show="isLoggedIn()"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i></a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: product in products -->
    </tbody></table>

</div>
```

I hade made following code but it's not correct in my opinion.

```
 element.all(by.css('.ng-binding')).each(function(element, index)
             {
             element.getText().then(function (text)
             {


             });
             })
```

notice I got 'Apple Pomace' in two places that's why its important to iterate through the td-class 'ng-binding'.

Could someone help me

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to just access the td you can use this:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.table td', 'Apple Pomace'))
```

In case if you would like to filter the rows in the table by the product and get the  element you can use below code snippet:

```
element.all(by.repeater('product in products')).filter(function(elem, index) {
  return elem.element(by.cssContainingText('td', 'Apple Pomace')).isPresent();
}).first();
```

Comment: when i try the last code snippet I get element is not a function.

Comment: thats because `by.repeater()` is made for `element.all()`... start with `element.all(by.repeater(...` and it will work.

Comment: Yeah my bad I have updated the code.. please try now

Comment: Thanks works better now though,
How do I add an expect to validate :

 element.all(by.repeater('product in products')).filter(function(elem, index) {
                return elem.element(by.cssContainingText('td', 'Apple Pomace')).isPresent();
            }).first();

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just use isDisplayed() over the above element and assert it to be true.

Comment: @Rakesh could you please send me an updated snipet where all is included I tested but did not find this working.

Thank you in advance